# Passing html search box string which is not submitted yet to python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a html search box.
If users hit their keyboard, I would like to pass this variable which is not submitted yet to python flask.
I have no idea how to handle this.
First code is html search box part and second code is python flask code.

```
<br> <input name="Country" type="text" id="Country" placeholder="Enter Country" oninput="myFunction()"/> oninput:  <span id="result"></span>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
//          result.innerHTML = Country.value;
            result.innerHTML = output;
        }; 
    </script>
```

```
@auth.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def autoComplete():
    country = request.form[Country.value]
    output = autoCompletion.init(country)
    return render_template("search.html", output=output)
```

Is there any way that passing a html search box string which is not submitted yet to python flask?
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Are you hosting a webpage using python flask? If you're hosting a webpage, you need to make a POST request from your document to that webpage.

Comment: Yes, I am.  Do you see any problem country = request.form[Country.value] in here?

Comment: You can request the data of the form field via the name of the field. So the expression would be `country = request.form['Country']`.
However, I think you want to use an Ajax GET request to get the data for your autocompletion. Thus, the page is not reloaded, but data is transferred asynchronously, which is then integrated into the page.

Comment: country = request.form['Country'] I thought this one is for only when the user submit it.

Comment: I am trying to pass the variable before the user submit it

Comment: You cannot query the form field using flask without the data being sent to the server. You can use javascript to request data from the server without the complete form being sent.

Comment: Flask is on the server side and the template is also put together on the server side. Changes can then only be made in the browser with javascript. Data can be reloaded dynamically and the page can be changed.

Comment: So if you want to receive data without sending the form, use asynchronous Javascript (AJAX) to make a request in the background.

Comment: Make a post request using asynchronous Javascript like Detlef said. You can use hidden input forms to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example using AJAX without ever submitting the form.

With every change within the form field, a request is sent to the server in the background. The data received are then added to the datalist assigned to the form field.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/complete')
def complete():
    countries = ['China', 'India', 'USA']
    country = request.args.get('country', '')
    results = [x for x in countries if x.startswith(country)]
    return jsonify(results=results)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="country" list="countries" placeholder="Enter Country" />
      <datalist id="countries"></datalist>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        let countryField = document.querySelector("input[name='country']");
        countryField.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
          fetch(`/complete?country=${encodeURIComponent(countryField.value)}`)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
              const dataList = document.getElementById("countries");
              dataList.innerHTML = "";
              
              const results = data.results;
              results.forEach(item => {
                let elem = document.createElement("option");
                elem.setAttribute("value", item);
                dataList.appendChild(elem);
              });

            })
            .catch(err => console.error("Error:", err));
        }, false);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code could certainly be improved, but it illustrates the possibility of obtaining data dynamically without reloading the page or finally sending the form.
To make your work easier, I recommend using libraries like jQuery.